# Conky display problem on restart "extra newlines"

Tags: crunchbang, conky

I've been using conky for a while and been tweaking it every once in a while but lately I've got this problem.

When I restart `conky` or the system, it displays extra new lines but when I make a simple modification and save the `.conkyrc` the new lines disappear.

What can be causing this and how can I fix it? I'm using Cruchbang 11.